# How to send @Model value to jquery function

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have asp.net mvc4 project where on edit page I try to send value from model to jquery function as variable.

This code isn't work, nothing hit, does anybody know how can I get value from model without setting hidden properties.

Edit:

```
@model WebForTesting.Models.Form.ProfForm

<script>

    $(document).ready(function () {
        setOptionValue();
    });

    function setOptionValue() {
        alert('@(Model.ChildrenId)');
    }
</script>
```

I'm sure that ChildrenId isnt null

Comment: This looks correct as far as it goes. Show us more code: what's the model declaration at the top of the view? What's the model itself look like? What code is calling this function? The alert won't fire unless some other JavaScript calls setOptionValue(). Try just calling the alert without putting it inside a function.

Comment: Read the generated source.

Comment: Where is this function located? It should be located in .cshtml, not in .js file otherwise you will have to use some global variable in your .js and then set it's value in .cshtml like someVar = @Model.someIntValue;

Comment: This is a .cshtml page

Comment: Any errors in your javascript console? Is jQuery loaded properly? What happens if you add an alert outside of the function?

Comment: So it must work. You should check generated HTML.

Comment: @JasonP Yes I have an error in console: Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined

Comment: Have you included jQuery?

Comment: :) add <script /> tag and link to jquery

Comment: @BorHunter jQuery isn't loaded. Google or search SO for that error, you'll get plenty of results.

Comment: @DmitrySikorsky what do you mean?

Comment: I mean that your code uses jquery ($(document).ready() function), but $ is not defined, so you have to add reference to jquery file in your html's head section.

Comment: possible duplicate of [JQuery - $ is not defined](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2194992/jquery-is-not-defined)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use `$(document).ready()`, see below:

```
<script>
    setOptionValue();
    function setOptionValue() {
        alert('@(Model.ChildrenId)');
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function setOptionValue() {
    alert("@(Model.ChildrenId)");
}
```

Comment: @BorHunter If it doesn't work are you positive your Model is filled? Are you getting any errors? What does the ViewSource look like at time of rendering? "It doesn't work" is an answer usually reserved for users.